# Architecture-generic InterlockedIncrement for 32/64-bit

Tags: c++, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, interlocked, interlocked-increment

What is the best way to use the C++ InterlockedIncrement functionality generic to both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures? (There are separated functions)

Is there a better way than using the `#if _W64` preprocessor command?

Comment: You can use C++11 atomic types.

Comment: The question you should be asking is why you are using different integer types for your 32 and 64 bit versions. Perhaps you can show the declaration of the variable on which you wish to operate.

Comment: You can use the C pre-processor paste operator to build a macro that resolvesto the right name for your system.

Comment: This is a good answer. However, I can't use it in my project. Are there other alternatives?

Comment: Please do tell us what type variable you are operating on

Comment: You are using C++, let the language's support for function overloads sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, since you're using C++:

```
inline LONGLONG __cdecl InterlockedIncrement(LONGLONG volatile *Addend)
{
  return InterlockedIncrement64(Addend);
);
```

Now you can unconditionally call `InterlockedIncrement` on either 32 bits or 64 bits variables, in both 32 and 64 bits builds.

Comment: May I have an explanation for this?